# Combine `if` condition with `id` in github actions

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

```
jobs:
   steps:
      - name: Get  Test  config
        if: ${{ github.event.inputs.stage == 'test' }}
        id: config
        uses: ./azure-config/test/

      - name: Get  Test  config
        if: ${{ github.event.inputs.stage != 'developemnt' }}
        id: config
        run: ./azure-config/developemnt

      - name: Login to azure login
        uses: ./azure-login
        with:
          testId: ${{ steps.config.outputs.TEST_ID }}


azure-config/test/action.yml 

name: 'config'
description: 'provides  config environment'
     
outputs:
   TEST_ID:
      description: "the  test id"
      value: 123456ab-1234-3456-2345-fe232343fdf  
runs:
   using: "composite"
   steps:
      - name: provide common config variables
        id: config
        run: echo "providing environment variables"
        shell: bash
```

In the above code, the ids config are same, i want to load the  config based on the stage which i get  it from event (github.event.inputs.stage)

How the **uses** attribute make dynamic

uses: ./azure-config/{{ github.event.inputs.stage }}/ => context not supported here

Comment: You're problem is that you're defining the `id: meta` twice

Comment: @rethab yes, but i want to reuse the workflow for dev and test stage. In the below jobs i used the id to read some configs 

for ex) market: ${{ steps.config.outputs.MARKET }}

sample config

`outputs:
  MARKET:
    description: "test"
    value: test

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: test
      id: meta
      run: echo "providing test variables"
      shell: bash`

Comment: Please update your question to show a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @rethab updated the code, can you please check

Comment: You're still using the same `id` twice.

Comment: @rethab  yes because I used the id reference for the below jobs and the id loads based on the stage input, I want the uses to attribute as a dynamic path 

- name: Login to azure login
    uses: ./azure-login
    with:
      testId: ${{ steps.config.outputs.TEST_ID }}